# JSON Schema Validation based on a property

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have been trying to get my JSON schema right. I have a `boolean` property based on which I have to determine the required properties. Below is my sample `JSON` which I want to fail the validation with `item3` not present.

```
{
  "item1": true,
  "item2": "ABC"
}
```

This is the JSON which I want the validation to pass

```
{
  "item1": true,
  "item2": "ABC",
  "item3": {
    "subItem1": "ABC",
    "subItem2": "BAC"
  }
}
```

Similarly, if the `item1` is `false`, then the validation should pass for both the above JSON's.

My JSON schema for the same is as below.

```
{
    "definitions": {},
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The Root Schema",
    "properties": {
        "item1": {
            "$id": "#/properties/item1",
            "type": "boolean",
            "title": "The Item1 Schema",
            "default": false,
            "examples": [
                true
            ]
        },
        "item2": {
            "$id": "#/properties/item2",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Item2 Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
                "ABC"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "item3": {
            "$id": "#/properties/item3",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The Item3 Schema",
            "required": [
                "subItem1",
                "subItem2"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "subItem1": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/item3/properties/subItem1",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Subitem1 Schema",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "AAA"
                    ],
                    "pattern": "^(.*)$"
                },
                "subItem2": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/item3/properties/subItem2",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Subitem2 Schema",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "BAC"
                    ],
                    "pattern": "^(.*)$"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["item1"],
    "allOf": [{
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "item1": {
                    "enum": [
                        true
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "required": [
                "item2",
                "item3"
            ]
        },
        "else": {
            "required": [
                "item2"
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

My validation always fails.

If `item1` is true, `subItem2` should be required.
If `item1` is false, then `item3` is not required, but should still validate if included.

Comment: What I see in your schema is, if item1 is true, then item2 and item3 are required, otherwise, only item2 is required. Is that your intent? I'm not totally clear what your goal is. Could you provide example JSON you want to validate successfully and example JSON you want to fail validation please?

Comment: I have added a sample JSON in the description. Just the toggle change is from true to false. @Relequestual

Comment: From your description of what you want in your question, it looks like you have your `then` and `else` the wrong way round, but I can't tell because your schema and what you say you want seems to be in contradiction. Hence why I asked if you could provide JSON you want to pass and fail, because currently it's unclear.

Comment: @RelequestualAdded the JSON samples

Comment: Your if/then/else block works correctly in terms of validation. The example JSON you provided that you expect to pass, fails, because you have required that `item3` has a property of `subItem1` and `subItem2`, but it does not.

Comment: You can run quick checks using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: @Relequestual How to handle that kind of case? I need `subItem1` and `subItem2` also to be based on the requirement of `Item3`.

Comment: You fixed your example JSON and now it passes as you requested. If you have further questions, I'd ask you consider asking a new question, because I've solved the issue you presented with the schema and instances provided. (If you change the question, it's going to get confusing for others.)

Comment: Alternatively, if you wish to discuss this in longer form, please join the JSON Schema slack via json-schema.org. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if`/`then`/`else` block works correctly in terms of validation.

The example JSON you provided that you expect to pass, fails, because you have required that `item3` has a property of `subItem1` and `subItem2`, but it does not.

Now you've updated your example JSON that should pass to correct `item3` containing `subItem1` and `subItem2`, the validation passes with the schema you've provided.

---

Additionally, you want, If I understand correctly:

> If item1 is true, subItem2 should be required. If item1 is false, then
>   item3 is not required, but should still validate if included.

Move the schema that makes `subItem3` required from `item3` to your `then` clause. This will make it so `subItem3` is only "required" if your `if` schema validates successfully (`item1` is `true`)

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "properties": {
    "item1": {
      "$id": "#/properties/item1",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Item1 Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    },
    "item2": {
      "$id": "#/properties/item2",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Item2 Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "ABC"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "item3": {
      "$id": "#/properties/item3",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Item3 Schema",
      "required": [
        "subItem1"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subItem1": {
          "$id": "#/properties/item3/properties/subItem1",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Subitem1 Schema",
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "AAA"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "subItem2": {
          "$id": "#/properties/item3/properties/subItem2",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Subitem2 Schema",
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "BAC"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "item1"
  ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "item1": {
            "enum": [
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "item2",
          "item3"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "item3": {
            "required": [
              "subItem2"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "required": [
          "item2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If `Item3` is required then all the subItems as required. Else, the requirement under the `Item3` should be nullified.

Comment: This is currently what happens. In your example JSON you expect to pass, if you remove item3`, validation fails because `item1` is true, which triggers the `then` block of your `if` block, which then makes `item3` required, and therefore you fail validation.

Comment: If you have additional JSON pass / fail examples which are not working as you expect, please share them, and test using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net

Comment: `{
  "item1": true,
  "item2": "ABC",
  "item3": {
    "subItem1": "ABC",
    "subItem2": "BAC"
  }
}` This JSON fails the requirement of subItems if item3 is required.

Comment: This passes validation. You said in your question that you expected that JSON instance to pass validation. I'm confused.

Comment: It asses the validation. But, try removing one of the subItem for a true case? It dosent work.

Comment: Removing either of the subitems causes validation to fail. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: Then it does work according to how you expect. What "doesn't work"?

Comment: If `Item1` is `false`, then `Item3` is not required, but, it could be provided as part of the request. If provided, there are required subItems in the request. That should be validated based on the `Item1` flag and not be made mandatory, where as if Item3 has required fields on subItems, then even when `Item3` is not required, the validation fails due to the required subItems.

Comment: OK! Solved. Will update your question, followed by my answer.