# Validating that a property value exists withing the keys of an object

Tags: jsonschema

Wise crowd,

I already have a working JSON Schema (v0.7) to validate my data. This is an example of valid JSON:

```json
{
  "people": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "bob" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I need to a bunch of strings in it:

```json
{
  "people": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "bob", "appears_in": "long_string_id_1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "ann", "appears_in": "long_string_id_1" }
    ...
  ],
  "long_strings": {
    "long_string_id_1": "blah blah blah.....",
    ...
  }
}
```

What I need is:

- a value for key `appears_in` MUST be a key of the `long_strings` object
- (optional) a key of the `long_strings` object MUST be used as value in on of the `appears_in` key

[Property dependencies](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-dependencies) are nice, but don't seem to address my needs.

Any idea?

---

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840926/json-schema-validation-based-on-a-property) is not a duplicate, because I do not know the values in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Schema Validation based on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840926/json-schema-validation-based-on-a-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. You cannot do this in JSON schema. You cannot reference data in your schema.

Comment: Too bad, but I guess this is the price to pay to have something simpler than an `XML` schema. Thank you for your work on `JSON` Schema and for this answer.